# EOF when performing async_read_some() on TCP socket... But connection is still up

Tags: c++, linux, boost-asio, tcpclient

I'm investigating on a strange issue on a piece of code that handle a TCP socket connection: every 10 minutes our client receive an EOF error when reading data using boost async_read_some(). 
This usually occurs when the client <-> server connection is lost and therefore our client gracefully close the connection and then reopen it.

However, when looking deeper for the cause of the EOF error I found that:

1. The server does not receive the same EOF error as client (they are both using the same code to handle communication) while it succesfully detect the client disconnection when I kill the client process.
2. Connection is actually still up: disabling the reconnection code and ignoring the error, client and server goes on exchanging data without problems...
3. Doing as in point 2, the EOF error does not occur anymore, so it seems that it occurs only one time, just after 10 minutes form a connection.

Does anyone have any idea of why i got that EOF? I'm using Boost v1.56.0 on Gentoo Linux.

Thank you in advance.
SiS.

EDIT: This is a simplified version of the code which give me the issue (sorry, but I can't post the actual one):

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <cstddef>

static const unsigned int g_reconnect_time = 15; // Seconds

class conn_t
{
public:

    conn_t( std::string ip, int port, boost::asio::io_service& io_service ) :
        m_tcp_host(ip),
        m_tcp_port(port),
        m_io_service( io_service ),
        m_socket( io_service ),
        m_reconnect_interval( g_reconnect_time ),
        m_reconnect_timer( io_service, m_reconnect_interval )   
    {
    }


    ~conn_t()
    {
        disconnect();
    }   


    bool connect()
    {
        using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
        tcp::resolver resolver( m_io_service );
        tcp::resolver::query query( tcp_host, m_tcp_port);
        tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve( query );
        tcp::resolver::iterator end;
        boost::system::error_code error = boost::asio::error::host_not_found;

        while ( error && ( endpoint_iterator != end ) )
        {
            m_socket.close();
            m_socket.connect( *endpoint_iterator++, error );
        }

        if ( error ) 
        {
            // Bail out and schedule for retry:
            queue_reconnect();
            return false;
        }

        if ( !m_socket.is_open() )
            return false;

        read_data();
        return true;
    }


    void disconnect()
    {
        m_socket.close();
    }


    void read_data()
    {
        m_socket.async_read_data_some( boost::asio::buffer( m_buff ),
            [this]( const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t len )
            {
                if ( handle_error( error ) )
                {
                     std::cerr << "Error read_dataing data: " << std::endl;
                    reconnect();
                } 
                else 
                {
                    std::cerr << "got " << len << " bytes of data" );
                    // process data here...
                    read_data();
                }
            } );
    }


    void reconnect()
    {
        queue_reconnect();
    }


private:

    bool handle_error ( const boost::system::error_code& error )
    {
        if ( error && error != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted ) 
        {
            std::cerr << "Socket i/o error: " << error.message() << std::endl;
            boost::system::error_code ignored_ec;
            m_socket.shutdown( boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ignored_ec );
            m_socket.close();

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    void queue_reconnect()
    {
        auto new_deadline = m_reconnect_timer.expires_at() + m_reconnect_interval;

        if ( new_deadline > boost::asio::deadline_timer::traits_type::now() )
            m_reconnect_timer.expires_at( new_deadline );
        else
            m_reconnect_timer.expires_from_now( m_reconnect_interval );

        m_reconnect_timer.async_wait( boost::bind( &conn_t::start, this ) );

    }

private:

    std::string tcp_host;
    int m_tcp_port;
    boost::asio::io_service& m_io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket  m_socket;
    boost::posix_time::seconds m_reconnect_interval;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer m_reconnect_timer;
    char m_buff[1024];
};
```

Comment: Very hard to tell, could be the underlying network stack. But to be sure of whenever it might be boost asio related: Please post your boost code, hopefully your tcp connection class.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], hard to debug code we can't see or run ourselves. Try using wireshark, look out for TCP "RST" packets.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the code as request.

Comment: Boost is not necessarily bug free, believe it or not. It's possible that you're hitting some kind of edge case where it attempts to read for 0 bytes. I scanned over some of the Boost asio code and there's some places that it checks for 0 byte reads. And other places where it doesn't! If you can often reproduce it, you might try running your program under `strace` to a log file. After the problem happens see if it logged a system call to read for 0 bytes, returning 0. Which would get confused with EOF, which also returns 0 bytes.

Comment: I don't know the source of the issue, but the given code has a memory issue: When the connection is closed (e.g. through `disconnect()`), any given `read/read_data` will be cancelled, and the callbacks for the failure will be called. These will try to access members of the connection again, by either trying to close the socket again or trying a new read attempt on it.

Comment: Thank you guys, I will check.